# Implementing IProvideClassInfo on C# COM Object

Tags: c#, com, interop, com-interop, wsh

I'm trying to implement the `IProvideClassInfo` on a C# COM object so its events can be used from Windows Script Host (WSH). I've managed to implement the interface and trace a call in to my `GetClassInfo` method. However, hooking up the events fails with `Cannot connect object`.

Has anyone managed to do this?

This is my script code (JScript):

```
function AP\_GetActionsResponse ()
{           
WScript.Echo ("AP\_GetActionsResponse event");
}

// It fails on this 
var obj = WScript.CreateObject ("Promotions.Promotion", "AP_");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out - You must specify a DispId on the event interface or it doesn't work.

There's no need to implement IProvideClassInfo, but you can if you want.